# Creating categories based on rows in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, categories

I have the following table called "Animal".

```
Animal Drink
Dog    Water
Dog    Water
Dog    Water
Cat    Milk
Cat    Milk
Cat    Water
```

I am trying to create categories based on the type of drink the animal is drinking and the result would be.

```
Animal Drink
Dog    Water
Cat    Mixed
```

I have tried various case statements but have been unsuccessful.  The issue is that I am comparing rows (instead of columns), which has proven to be quite difficult for me.

Essentially, I want to single out animals that only drink water. 
If an animal only drinks water than it would be categorized as "Water".  If an animal drinks water and anything else, than it would be categorized as "Mixed".  If the animal does not drink any water, then it would categorized "NonWater"

Comment: Is the [Teradata] tag relevant?

Comment: Teradata has different syntax in some cases compared to others such as MySQL or oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can simply use a group by expression :

```
SELECT
  animal,
  CASE
    WHEN (sum_other = 0) THEN 'Water'
    WHEN (sum_water = 0) THEN 'NonWater'
    ELSE 'Mixed'
  END
FROM (SELECT
  animal,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN (drink = 'Water') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS sum_water,
  SUM(CASE
    WHEN (drink <> 'Water') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) AS sum_other
FROM my_table
GROUP BY animal) A
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked great!  I didn't even think of using a select from the "from" statement

Comment: Of course you don't need a nested Select, you can do the `SUM(CASE..` directly within the outer `CASE`

Answer (score 0):

May seem complex, but will work I think, Although I have not tested:

```
SELECT
      A.[Animal]
    , [Drink] = IIF(A.[Cnt] > 1, 'Mixed', T.[Drink]) 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
          [Animal]
        , [Cnt] = Count(*)  
    FROM
        [Table]
    GROUP BY
          [Animal]
        , [Drink]
    ) AS A
    OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 
            *
        FROM
            [Table] AS T
        WHERE
            A.Animal = T.Animal
    ) AS T
```

Answer (score 0):

Count up the number of drinks by animal and use CASE:

```
SELECT Animal,
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Drink)=1
THEN Drink ELSE 'Mixed' END AS Drink
FROM T
GROUP BY Animal
```

Comment: I tried using this one, but it was making me add "drink" to my group by which in turn resulted in multiple rows per animal instead of just a single row. IE cast showed up twice because of "milk" and "water"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
t.Animal
,'Mixed'
FROM #TEMP t
GROUP BY t.Animal HAVING count(DISTINCT t.Drink) > 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
t.Animal
,(SELECT Top 1 t1.Drink FROM #TEMP t1 WHERE t1.Animal = t.Animal) 
FROM #TEMP t
GROUP BY t.Animal HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.Drink) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

or something like this

```
select animal, drink from 
(select animal,
    rank() over (partition by animal order by  drink desc) as rn,
      case when rank() over (partition by animal order by  drink ) = 1
      then drink
      else 'mixed'
      end as drink
 from animal
)x
where x.rn = 1
group by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution :

```
SELECT Animal,
CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Drink)=1
THEN 
(SELECT DISTINCT Drink from my_table where Animal = T.Animal)
 ELSE 'Mixed' END AS Drink
FROM my_table as T
GROUP BY Animal
```